# How can I measure CPU and RAM usage of a function written in R, running on windows

Tags: r, profiling, benchmarking, cpu-usage, ram

How can I calculate CPU and RAM usage of a function written in R in windows operating system. Can I calculate the CPU Usage using proc.time() function

Comment: See the [Measuring Performance](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-measure.html) chapter of Advanced R for examples of different profiling techniques

Comment: For memory usage, I like to use ```pryr::mem_used()```.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CPU Usage Measurement and Calculation in R using proc.time()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217110/cpu-usage-measurement-and-calculation-in-r-using-proc-time)  (The same user asked 3 vesions of this question in 1 day.  They should probably all be closed as duplicates of the last one which has an attempt, and an answer.)