# CPU Usage Measurement and Calculation in R using proc.time()

Tags: r, profiling, benchmarking

How can I calculate CPU usage of a function written in R in windows operating system. Can I calculate the CPU Usage using proc.time() function

I tried the following way

```
fibb <- function (n) {
  if (n < 3) {
    return(c(0,1)[n])
  } else {
    return(fibb(n - 2) + fibb(n -1))
  }
}

t2 <- proc.time()
fibb(30)
print("Time two")
x=proc.time() - t2
cpu_usage<-(as.numeric(x)[[2]]/as.numeric(x)[[1]])*100 # system time/user time
print(paste("Cpu usage:", round(cpu_usage,2)))
```

Is it correct way ? else could you please help me with this?

Comment: You could use the `system.time` function or actually profile your code: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I would interpret "CPU usage" as "% CPU" as shown by linux top or windows task manager. But I suspect that's not what OP is interested in because they are timing code execution.

Comment: Utilization percent is a term applied to the portion of a time period that a component is doing work, divided by the total amount of time in the time period. The result is multiplied by 100 to obtain a percentage.
For a CPU, the busy time is spent processing program instructions. Here is an example of how to interpret a utilization rate of 70% for a 5-minute time period: "For 70% of the 5 minutes, the CPU was fully utilized."

Comment: and The ‘user time’ is the CPU time charged for the execution of user instructions of the calling process. The ‘system time’ is the CPU time charged for execution by the system on behalf of the calling process. that's why i wrote the code so

Comment: That is the most expensive way to do Fibonacci. A far far faster way is to just loop:  `f0 = f1 + f2; f2 = f1; f1 = f0;` repeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
t.start <- proc.time()
## <some R code>
t.end <- proc.time()
x <- t.end - t.start
```

I think the following are good measures of CPU usage:

```
## user / (user + system)
x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100 * m

## user / elapsed
x[[1]] / x[[3]] * 100
```

where `m` is the number of CPUs used in *<some R code>*.

- If `m = 1`, i.e., in serial computing, they should give close results;
- If `m > 1`, i.e., in parallel computing, they may differ (a lot) and I tend to trust the first one.

---

**example with `m = 1`**

Using OP's `fibb()` function to compute a Fibonacci number.

```
t.start <- proc.time()
fibb(30)
t.end <- proc.time()
x <- t.end - t.start

x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100
#[1] 99.3689

x[[1]] / x[[3]] * 100
#[1] 99.19817
```

**R-level parallel computing example with `m = 2`**

Matrix computation without optimized BLAS.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
t.start <- proc.time()
foo <- clusterApply(cl, c(4000, 4000), fun = function (n) crossprod(matrix(rnorm(n * n), n)))
t.end <- proc.time()
x <- t.end - t.start
stopCluster(cl)

x
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.723   0.375   6.324

x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100 * 2
#[1] 131.694

x[[1]] / x[[3]] * 100
#[1] 11.43264
```

Hmm?? Well, no surprising. Jobs are actually done on 2 other **R** processes, not in our working **R** session. CPU is basically idle for our working **R** session. I don't know how to get the right CPU usage. (Maybe do `proc.time()` in the function that is passed to `clusterApply` so we measure CPU usage for each slave **R** process separately?)

**FORTRAN/C/C++ parallel computing example with `m = 2`**

Matrix computation with OpenBLAS and 2 threads.

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(4000 * 4000), 4000)
t.start <- proc.time()
AA <- A %*% A
t.end <- proc.time()
x <- t.end - t.start

x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100 * 2
#[1] 197.1904

x[[1]] / x[[3]] * 100
#[1] 195.1596
```

---

**Note:**

If you have a big chunk of code that mixes serial and parallel computing, I advise breaking it into smaller chunks:

```
t.start <- proc.time()
## <R code chunk 1 - serial computing>
t.end <- proc.time()
x1 <- t.end - t.start
CPU.usage1 <- x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100

t.start <- proc.time()
## <R code chunk 2 - parallel computing with m CPUs>
t.end <- proc.time()
x2 <- t.end - t.start
CPU.usage2 <- x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100 * m

t.start <- proc.time()
## <R code chunk 3 - serial computing>
t.end <- proc.time()
x3 <- t.end - t.start
CPU.usage3 <- x[[1]] / (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) * 100
```

Comment: How can we verify it accurately? The values of the task manager are dynamic . how can I capture it for a function and compare with output of the script?

Comment: in other words How can we verify the code output with actual CPU usage?

Comment: Your `user / (user + system)` multiplying by `m` assumes that your workload parallelizes perfectly, no serial computation portions.  But assuming that kernel time is serial, for some reason.  Multiple threads can take page faults in parallel in the same process, triggering copy-on-write or zeroing a fresh page on two different cores at once.  Or obviously an interrupt handler.  I/O to a single file-descriptor is essential serialized, and to some degree so is modifying page tables to deallocate memory I think.  (Or TLB shootdown needs to affect all cores running a thread of the process.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi... emm, you are the expert and definitely know better than I do. My limited experience with normal computing in R gives me the impression that my simple calculation looks reasonable... Is there any better way? Or is it just not possible to do it by simply using "user", "system" and "elapsed"? BTW, good to talk to you again; it's been 4 years since my last question was answered by you. :)

Comment: A lot of linear algebra stuff does parallelize *very* well, but any time spent sleeping to wait for a lock is time when not all `m` threads are running.  Or while some threads have finished their portion of a parallel task, but others haven't, and there isn't new work for them to start on yet. (As in Amdahl's Law, most parallel programs have some serial portions).  And of course other tasks on the system might keep some CPU cores busy, not letting an R thread run even when it's ready to.

Comment: `(User+system) / elapsed` is the average number of CPU cores kept busy over that interval.  It's the number of CPU-seconds per real-time second, the defintion of CPU utilization.  @zainulabid: you can measure this externally from R with Linux `perf stat -I 1000 -e task-clock,cycles -p $(pidof R)` to print every second (-I 1000 ms), with CPU-time used during it, and average utilization calculated from that.  Also cycles/second, the average CPU frequency of the cores your threads ran on during that interval.